# Does ColdFusion keep usage logs?

Tags: logging, coldfusion

I would like to get some usage statistics for a ColdFusion application. The app is far too large to add any custom logging to each and every page. I know ColdFusion maintains error and exception logs, but does it maintain any sort of usage log, one entry per page load? I know there is a monitoring application launched via the Administrator, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

EDIT:

Adam Cameron and anthony point out, oh yeah, I never said what stats I'm looking for:

Bare minimum: the page loaded, date and time of the page load.
Would like to have: the authenticated user
Would really like but don't think I'm going to get: the elapsed time of each page request

The reason for that is that I've whipped up a small app to display usage statistics for Oracle Apex applications. I'd like to include statistics for ColdFusion as well.

Parsing through the Apache logs does seem to be one viable solution. There are minor issues with that, namely permissions and ownership of the logs. I was just hoping CF was doing it for me somewhere else.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using web analytics for this?

Comment: what sort of usage stats? how about your webserver logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onRequestEnd.cfm` at the root of your site to have a file that executes at the end of every request.

To further the answer based on your edited post, you can use `getTickCount`, `onRequestStart.cfm` and `onRequestEnd.cfm` to get the run time of the page. Like so:

### onRequestStart.cfm

```
<cfset startTime = getTickCount() />
```

### onRequestEnd.cfm

```
<cfset runTimeInMS = getTickCount() = startTime />
<cflog file="RunTimeLog" text="File completed in #runTimeInMS# ms" />
```

Comment: is there any reason why `onRequestEnd` is better then `onRequestStart` for this case?

Comment: No, just depends on if you want to log the start of a request, or the end. Either way will do fine.

Comment: I think that's the best solution to what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a log of what page requests have been made (ie: what URLs visitors to the site are hitting) then your web server will log that for you; there's nothing inbuilt into CF that does it.  However if you need CF to do it for some reason, then Dan's suggestion of OnRequestEnd.cfm is a good suggestion.  I think the web server solution here is "better" based on the fact it's done out of the box.

You don't, btw, really give enough detail as to what sort of metrics you are after.  This makes it difficult to give you a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using application.cfc file then you can add code onRequestEnd to make it available for whole site.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using application.cfc.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you don't just use Google Analytics?

http://www.google.com/analytics/

All you would need to do is embed the javascript on the page, and you would be good to go.